# Having trouble proving $4\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{5}-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{70}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{99}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

I know

$$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$
but how can I prove

> $$4\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{5}-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{70}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{99}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

I tried it, but I am getting large numbers using the above formula. I think there must be some trick to follow. Regards

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no trick here. You may use $$2\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}({2x\over1-x^2})$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $\tan \alpha = \frac 15$. Use the duplication formula $\tan 2A = \frac{2 \tan A}{1 - \tan^2 A}$ twice to obtain $\tan 4 \alpha = \frac{120}{119}$. Hence, $\tan{4 \alpha} - 1  = \frac{1}{119}$ and $\tan\left(4 
 \alpha  - \frac \pi 4\right) = \frac{\frac 1{119}}{ (1 + \frac{120}{119})} = \frac 1{239}$ from the fact that $\tan(A-B) = \frac{\tan A - \tan B}{1 + \tan A  \tan B}$. Hence, $\arctan \frac 1{239} = 4 \alpha - \frac \pi 4$.

On the other hand, $\arctan \frac 1{70} - \arctan \frac 1{99}$ can be calculated from the formula you gave at first, and it gives $\arctan \frac 1{239}$.

Hence, $\arctan \frac 1{70} - \arctan \frac 1{99} = 4 \arctan \frac 15 - \frac \pi 4$. Rearrange to get the desired result.

Note : the fact that $4 \alpha - \frac \pi 4 = \arctan \frac 1{239}$ is a very special one, called Machin's formula, named after John Machin, who used it to calculate digits of $\pi$ way back in $1706$. More about that on : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula.  There are some really amazing formulas on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(5+i)^4(90+i)/(70+i)=?$$